# ng-submit doesn't fire anything in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-submit

I have a basic problem and I can't understand why it isn't working

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="row writing">
        <p>{{slogan}}</p>
    </div>
    {{send()}} //check if the function is there
    <div class="container">
        <form name="userForm" ng-submit="send()" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <ng-form name="userMail">
                    <input name="mail" type="email" ng-model="varmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your mail" required>
                    <!--<p class="help-block" ng-show="userMail.mail.$invalid">Valid Email Required</p>-->
                </ng-form>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <ng-form name="userMarket">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="varmarket" class="form-control" placeholder="huhu"
                        required>
                </ng-form>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary flat-butt">{{butLabel}}</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I can see the function is there but the ng-submit doesn't fire anything.
Notice that this is isolated scope and the function was passed in successfully.

Thank you.

UPDATE: I created a Plunk here and it doesn't work either
http://plnkr.co/edit/CULSC4ajGfid25sEaT34?p=preview

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: there is nothing

Comment: Can you provide a Plunkr? Are you specifying the controller in your router?

Comment: I added a Plunkr in the post, so obviously it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

**There is nothing wrong with the code that you have posted *(functionally)*.**

1. Start debugging by checking your console for any error messages.
2. Take a look at your `send` function that your passing to the [`ngForm`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) directive, and that it's in scope.
3. Check your HTML markup for that file. Perhaps you have trailing `<form>` tags that are obfuscating the form you are targeting with your submit button.

If you are using nested controllers, try to make use of the "controller as" syntax so that you can avoid accessing your functions and variables from the $scope that's created from each one.

Also, I do not see why you have extra [`ngForm`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) directives around your inputs within the form. It doesn't appear to be necessary from what you've posted.

Here is your code working:

```js
// app.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

})();

// main.controller.js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainController($scope) {

    $scope.butLabel = "Submit";

    $scope.send = send;

    function send() {
      alert("Triggered!");
    }


  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="footer" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl">
  <div class="row writing">
    <p>{{slogan}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="send()" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <ng-form name="userMail">
          <input name="mail" type="email" ng-model="varmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your mail" required>
          <!--<p class="help-block" ng-show="userMail.mail.$invalid">Valid Email Required</p>-->
        </ng-form>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <ng-form name="userMarket">
          <input type="text" ng-model="varmarket" class="form-control" placeholder="Your favorite super-market (Franprix, Carrefour,...)" required>
        </ng-form>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary flat-butt">{{butLabel}}</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a Plunkr here and it isn't working on the Plunkr either: http://plnkr.co/edit/CULSC4ajGfid25sEaT34?p=preview

Comment: so in my code my code was a directive with isolated scope, maybe because of it ?

Answer (score 0):

So I find it, when I passed in the function I should have use "sendInfo()", not "sendInfo".

Thank you everyone !